# Guided random numbers

Tags: random, vhdl

I want to make code for a game called 'Dual N-Back'. The game works by showing squares moving on a 3x3 grid and when a square is on the same position as it was N times ago, the user has to press a button. The problem I am experiencing right now is that I want to have the squares appear on random locations on the grid, but I also want to force the game to have exactly 10 match opportunities out of 20 iterations of the game. How do I force this while still having the randomness of the square location built into the game?

The function has to be implemented in hardware using the VHDL language, so I can't afford using expensive mathematical functions.

Comment: You need to create a random full plan of moves ahead of time and reject it if it doesn't fulfil your criteria. That's probably the easiest solution by far. There's others but will need some AI

Comment: You might take a look at the "constrained random" features in the http://www.osvvm.org packages which may offer similar functionality. These are aimed at verification (in simulation) so may not be synthesisable.